# Combining two or more submit buttons into one

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have submit buttons for different section of the webpage. The submit button is used to update the forms and database with the text value in the form fields. Currently, each submit button updates the forms (tied to their respective PKEY id, "consideration_no") only in their own sections. I want to update all the sections forms with one button click.

As you can see from the code below, there are 2 submit buttons. I have tried to link two together through IDs but it did not work for me.

```
    // Include config file
    require_once "config.php";

    // Define variables and initialize with empty values
    $question = $answer = "";
    $question_err = $answer_err = "";

     if(isset($_POST["dg_no"]) && !empty($_POST["dg_no"])){

        //counter for array
        $counter = 0;

        // Get hidden input value
        $dg_no = $_POST['dg_no'];
        $consideration_no = $_REQUEST['consideration_no'];
        $answer = $_POST['answer'];

        // Check input errors before inserting in database
        if(empty($answer_err)){

            // Validate address address
            $input_answer = trim($_POST["answer"]);
            if(empty($input_answer)){
                $answer_err = "Please enter an answer.";     
            } else{
                $answer = $input_answer;
                $answer1[$counter] = $input_answer;
            }   

            // Prepare an Submit statement
            $sql = 'Update "PDPC".consideration SET answer=:answer WHERE consideration_no = :consideration_no';
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){

                $stmt->bindParam(":answer", $param_answer);
                $stmt->bindParam(":consideration_no", $param_consideration_no);
                //$stmt->bindParam(":dg_no", $param_dg_no);

                //Set Parameter in while loop, hence new set of parameter for every new form is created and executed. 
                //Could change the counter loop to a dynamic loop with foreach array. 
                while ($counter<15){    
                $param_answer = $answer[$counter];
                $param_consideration_no = $consideration_no[$counter];
                $stmt->execute();
                //$param_dg_no = $dg_no;
                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement

                    //debugggggg
    /*              $message = $consideration_no[$counter];
                    $message1 = $answer[$counter];
                    $message2 = 'lol';
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message, $message1, $message2 ');</script>";  */

                    $counter++;
                    //apparently redirecting can be placed in the loop, and fields will still get changed.
                    //header("location: home1.php?dm_no=".$_GET["dm_no"]);
                    header("location: home1.php?dm_no=".$_GET["dm_no"]);

                }

            }
                    if($stmt->execute()){
                    //Records Submitd successfully. Redirect to landing page
                    header("location: home1.php?dm_no=".$_GET["dm_no"]);
                    exit();
                } else{
                    echo "Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }

            // Close statement
            unset($stmt);
        }

        // Close connection
        unset($pdo);
    } else{
        /* --- DISPLAY/READ TABLE, SEE SECTIONS AND ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
        // Check existence of dg_no parameter before processing further
        if(isset($_GET["dg_no"]) && !empty(trim($_GET["dg_no"]))){

            // Get URL parameter
            $dg_no =  trim($_GET["dg_no"]);

            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM "PDPC".consideration WHERE (dg_fkey = :dg_no AND code_no = 1) ORDER BY consideration_no';
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                $stmt->bindParam(":dg_no", $param_no);

               // Set parameters
               //$param_no = $dg_no;
                $param_no = trim($_GET["dg_no"]);


                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

                    SubSection($subsection1_1); //Consent Collection Subsection
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        // Retrieve individual field value

                        $consideration_no = $row["consideration_no"];
                        $question = $row["question"];
                        $answer = $row["answer"];
                        $dg_no = $_GET['dg_no'];

                        //...time to show the questions and answers with the while loop...
                        ?>

                              <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($answer_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <label><?php echo $question; ?></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="answer[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
                                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $answer_err;?></span>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="consideration_no[]"  value="<?php echo $consideration_no; ?>"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="dg_no" value="<?php echo $dg_no; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                        <?php

                        }

                        //...after the loop, show the Submit and Cancel button, coz we only need 1 set each section. 
                        ?>  

                                <input type="Submit" name = "$consideration_no[]" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                               </form>
                            </div>
                        <?php
                    } 
                }           
                else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }

        Section($section2); //Collection section
            // Prepare a select statement
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM "PDPC".consideration WHERE (dg_fkey = :dg_no AND code_no = 2) ORDER BY consideration_no';
            if($stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql)){
                // Bind variables to the prepared statement as parameters
                $stmt->bindParam(":dg_no", $param_no);

               // Set parameters
               //$param_no = $dg_no;
                $param_no = trim($_GET["dg_no"]);

                // Attempt to execute the prepared statement
                if($stmt->execute()){
                    if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){

                    SubSection($subsection2); //Consent Collection Subsection
                        while($row = $stmt->fetch()){
                        // Retrieve individual field value

                        $consideration_no = $row["consideration_no"];
                        $question = $row["question"];
                        $answer = $row["answer"];
                        $dg_no = $_GET['dg_no'];

                        //...time to show the questions and answers with the while loop...
                        ?>
                              <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                                <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($answer_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                                    <label><?php echo $question; ?></label>
                                    <input type="text" name="answer[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
                                    <span class="help-block"><?php echo $answer_err;?></span>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="consideration_no[]" value="<?php echo $consideration_no; ?>"/>
                                    <input type="hidden" name="dg_no" value="<?php echo $dg_no; ?>"/>
                                </div>
                        <?php
                        }

                        //...after the loop, show the Submit and Cancel button, coz we only need 1 set each section. 


                        ?>
                                <input type="Submit" name = "$consideration_no[]" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                                <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                               </form>
                            </div>
                        <?php   
                    } 
                }           

                else{
                    echo "Oops! Something went wrong. Please try again later.";
                }
            }


            // Close statement
            unset($stmt);
            // Close connection
            unset($pdo);
        }  

        else{
            // URL doesn't contain dg_no parameter. Redirect to error page
            header("location: error.php");
            exit();
        }   
    }
```

[I want it to update all the fields, in different sections, with one submit button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KECcA.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

your code was bit difficult to read, but from what i understood you are trying to combine two or more form submissions into one. It's quiet simple

```
<form method="POST" action="save.php">
   <input type=text name=name[] />
   <input type=text name=name[] />
</form>
```

by using the `[]` to identify the input element you can have multiple values with the same name where you can access them from the PHP script as an array.

For example the above example will produce an array as follows

```
<?php
   print_r($_POST['name']); //("name" => Array....
```

is this clear enough for you? if not drop a comment, i will explain more. As a side note i do recommend you look into using template engine, and also a framework in your coding project.

Comment: Hi thanks for getting back to me! I sort of understand what you mean. I'm trying it out right now and I could be doing it wrongly hence it's still not working for me but I'm trying to remove the </form> in the middle, to make it one form instead of multiple forms but it's not working for me. I'm already using name=consideration_no[] in my code.

Comment: yeah apologies about my coding. I'm an inexperienced coder and I'm new to php and html. I'll keep your advise in mind for the future

Comment: there is no reason to apologies, we all started from 0, i recommend you try to separate the html and php into separate files, this will make it easier for you to read. what you can also do is remove <form></form> from one section completely and then expand the form you are left with to introduce any additional logic

Comment: I separated the html into a new file to see the logic, and tried to remove the <form> </form> that's inbetween, however, when I open the last collapsible section, it instantly executes a submit action and brings me back to the home page.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I see when i separate the html into a new file. I tried to remove the excess forms but when I open the last collapsible section, it instantly executes a submit action and brings me back to the home page.

```
    <button class="collapsible"><?php echo $section ?></button>
    <div class="content">

    <button class="collapsible"><?php echo $subsection ?></button>
     <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">

                <?php
                //while loop start
                ?>

                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($answer_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label><?php echo $question; ?></label>
                            <input type="text" name="answer[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $answer_err;?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="consideration_no[]"  value="<?php echo $consideration_no; ?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="dg_no" value="<?php echo $dg_no; ?>"/>
                        </div>
                <?php
                //while loop ends
                ?>  

                        <input type="Submit" name = "$consideration_no[]" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                <?php
                //while loop start
                ?>
                      <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars(basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])); ?>" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group <?php echo (!empty($answer_err)) ? 'has-error' : ''; ?>">
                            <label><?php echo $question; ?></label>
                            <input type="text" name="answer[]" class="form-control" value="<?php echo $answer; ?>">
                            <span class="help-block"><?php echo $answer_err;?></span>
                            <input type="hidden" name="consideration_no[]" value="<?php echo $consideration_no; ?>"/>
                            <input type="hidden" name="dg_no" value="<?php echo $dg_no; ?>"/>
                        </div>
                <?php
                //while loop ends
                ?>  
                        <input type="Submit" name = "$consideration_no[]" class="btn btn-primary" value="Submit">
                        <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
                       </form>
                    </div>
                <?php
```